# Problem in sign out and change in user account

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

In my site after i log in with a user, and when I try to logout or try to signin with different user, again it only log in with the same user. After logout also I remain in Same user.

Comment: This question needs a **lot** more information. What code are you using for sign-in and sign-out? (I assume this is a programming question, since this is a programming Q&A site.) What else can you tell us about your app/environment/testing/things you've already tried? Etc. Etc.

Comment: i am using signout.aspx page for sign out and its a windows based authentication..The code in signout.aspx is                  function _spBodyOnLoad()
{
 try
 {
  document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
 }
 catch (e) {}
 window.close();
}

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Security Settings** for appropriate zone in Internet Explorer options.

[image]

If you're using default settings, **the sign out function does virtually nothing**, because next time you visit the site you get signed in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. It seems to be a weird behavior from SharePoint. But if you refresh the page two to three times the SharePoint page will show the right user at the top right.